# Is this a correct output for sum Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, sum

For this basic algorithm:

```
begin
 input n;
 sum:= 0;
   for i:=1 to n do
 sum:=sum+i;
 output sum;
 end
```

If we say `n=3` then am I right in saying the final output sum would be 6?
If it is not then please could someone explain why!

Apologies if formatting is off, I'm not sure if I got it right.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want ?

Comment: I want to know if I'm right in what im saying! I'm a little unsure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This algorithm works. Although you can get a more efficient algorithm by using

```
begin
input n;
sum:= n*(n + 1) / 2;
output sum;
end
```